# What is the encryption used in Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, password-encryption

Good day!

I am new at Asp.Net and I want to re-create the registration of Asp.Net. I am trying to find the encryption code and insert command used by Asp.Net default. As the title suggests, I want to know what is the encryption method used? Is it a hash or md5 or other method and where exactly can I find the code?

Usually, the **Register** backend code has this command

```
var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = Username.Text, Email = Username.Text };
IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);
```

I know that the signInManager is not the command, I tried inspecting `IdentityResult` but found nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hashing isn't encryption. MD5 is a hash algorithm and it is obsolete and insecure.

Comment: Most of ASP.NET is open sourced https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource So if your goal is to "re-create the registration of Asp.Net", make sure you go over what Microsoft wrote first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To Encrypt the Password**

```
string Password = EncryptString(Password.Text);
```

> Here I'm Encrypting the Password Using UTF8... So You can Store the
> Encrypted Password In Database...

```
public static string EncryptString(string str)
{
    return Encrypt(str, "!#$a54?3");
}

private static string Encrypt(string stringToEncrypt, string sEncryptionKey)
{
    
    byte[] key = { };
    byte[] IV = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 };
    byte[] inputByteArray; //Convert.ToByte(stringToEncrypt.Length)
    try
    {
        key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sEncryptionKey.Substring(0, 8));
        DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        inputByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

**To Decrypt the Password**

> Same Way you can Decrypt the Password

```
public static string DecryptString(string str)
{
    return Decrypt(str, "!#$a54?3");
}

private static string Decrypt(string stringToDecrypt, string sEncryptionKey)
{
    
    byte[] key = { };
    byte[] IV = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 }; //try {&H12, &H34, &H56, &H78, &H90, &HAB, &HCD, &HEF}
    byte[] inputByteArray = new byte[stringToDecrypt.Length];
    try
    {
        key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sEncryptionKey.Substring(0, 8));
        DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        inputByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(stringToDecrypt.Replace(" ", "+"));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateDecryptor(key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        return encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray());

    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Note:- Use the Same Key for Encrypt and Decrypt the Password ...Here I'm using **!#$a54?3**